# Rails: Accessing image files after being uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload, asset-pipeline

I am writing a Ruby on Rails 5 app. I just learned how to upload an image without using paperclip,carrierwave, or refile.  I have used refile in the past but for this app, I wanted to learn how to do it with out those third party gems.  And it was not that difficult to do. I have successfully uploaded a file.  My problem is accessing the image afterwards!  I thought this would be rather simple. But NO!

I have image files being uploaded to "/public/images/page/image.jpg"

I have added "/public/images/page" to the assets path in app/initializers/assets.rb

I have tried straight img tag like this:

```
<img class="pic left" src="/public/images/page/mars01.jpg" alt="Mars01" />
```

I get a "(No route matches [GET] "/public/images/page/mars01.jpg")" error.
I have tried:

```
<%= image_tag "/public/images/page/#{@page.image}", class: 'pic left' %>
```

basically the same as  tag, get same results. Also tried:

```
<img class="pic left" src='<%= image_path "#{@page.image}" %>' />
```

still get routing error, but only looking in "/images" directory. I am still in development mode, so I thought that image_path would be the correct path.

What is the correct way of accessing an image, that was just uploaded to a directory outside of the asset pipeline? That will work in development or production env?  I really thought this would be straight forward.

Comment: You are trying to access uploaded static images, you can't use the assets pipeline. I would remove the setting you added to assets.rb and point directly to the image path with: `Rails.root.join( 'public', 'image', 'mars01.jpg' ).to_s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing for anyone interested.

in my controller I did this:

```
# default to development go to app/assets/images
path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', uploaded_io.original_filename)
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'
  # change only if in production to public/assets/images
  Rails.root.join('public', 'assets', 'images', uploaded_io.original_filename)
end
File.open(path, 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(uploaded_io.read)
end
```

Based on RAILS_ENV; if development, images will go to app/assests/images folder; if in production they go to public/assets/images.

And using a straight forward image_tag:

```
<%= image_tag "#{@page.image}" %>
```

worked like a charm. Well at least I know it works in development setting. 
Thanks to those that responded. (Mat, and Nagasaki)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to give the whole path to image within `image_tag`, you just give the image name with the sub directory if it exists.

So try `<%= image_tag "#{@page.image}", class: 'pic left' %>`.

And please read more about asset pipeline.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html